# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Book'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, razor, model-view-controller

This is what I have on my controller:

```
ViewData.Add("Book", results.Select(x=> new SelectListItem() { Text = x.BookTitle}));
```

And on my view

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("Book", book as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

where book is an object with `ViewData["Book"]`, and I keep on getting that error message when i trigger my Create Function.

How can i solve this?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I keep on getting that error message when i trigger my Create Function.